# How to assign unique country ID number in panel data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In my dataset, I want to create unique country id numbers. Any help?

```
library(dplyr)
library(pwt10)
```

dataframe looks like

`country isocode year currency gdp inflation ...`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A`

`...`

`Argentina ARG    1950 Peso    130   60 ...`

I want to create another column of country ID variable (`id_num`), whose values are written in descending order (1,2,3,....) so that it looks like the following:

`country isocode year currency gdp inflation ID`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A     1`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A     1`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A     1`

`Aruba   ABW     1950  N/A     N/A   N/A     1`

`...`

`Argentina ARG    1950 Peso    130   60 ...  5`

`
I was wondering how to create the unique country ID column. Any help?

Comment: I see you included you desired output: why does Aruba have ID 1 and ID 2?

Comment: Sorry mistake just updated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your task correctly you are looking to build a second (first is the isocode) group identification by sequencial numbering of groups. One way to achive this is the cur_group_id() function from dplyr. Here is a toy example you should be able to adapt to your data.frame:

```
library(dplyr)
# dummy data
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c") ,
                 col2 = 1:6)

df %>%
    # arrange the data in growing order for column you want to build sequential group ID from/for
    dplyr::arrange(col1) %>%
    # build the groupings
    dplyr::group_by(col1) %>%
    # add new column : sequenctial group id
    dplyr::mutate(ID = dplyr::cur_group_id()) %>%
    # always ungroup to prevent unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  col1   col2    ID
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 a         1     1
2 a         2     1
3 b         3     2
4 b         4     2
5 b         5     2
6 c         6     3
```

Comment: I think I follow your way but it doesn't generate id variable. Can you check the following my code? `pwt10.0 %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(pwt10.0$country) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(pwt10.0$country) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::cur_group_id()) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()`

Comment: you have to call the columns by names in the dplyr pipe, not the column it seld. Try this: pwt10.0 %>%    
dplyr::arrange(country) %>%   
dplyr::group_by(country) %>%   
dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::cur_group_id()) %>%   
dplyr::ungroup()

Comment: Still I can't really find id variable after running your code and when I view by `View(pwt10.0)`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I just tried it with your test data and the id column shows up: 
pwt10.0 %>% dplyr::arrange(country) %>% dplyr::group_by(country) %>% dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::cur_group_id()) %>% dplyr::ungroup() %>% dplyr::select(country, id)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that `"ARM"` should return 1, `"AUS"` should return 2 and so on.

Maybe you can try this answer with `match`.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- pwt10.0 %>% 
  filter(isocode %in% comparison_states) %>% 
  distinct(isocode) %>% 
  mutate(id_num = match(comparison_states, isocode))

result

#         isocode id_num
#ARM-1950     ARM      1
#AUS-1950     AUS      2
#CAN-1950     CAN      3
#CHN-1950     CHN      4
#GBR-1950     GBR      5
#ITA-1950     ITA      6
#JPN-1950     JPN      7
#LUX-1950     LUX      8
#NOR-1950     NOR      9
#NZL-1950     NZL     10
#SGP-1950     SGP     11
#SWE-1950     SWE     12
#THA-1950     THA     13
#TWN-1950     TWN     14
#USA-1950     USA     15
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to do but after applying your code, the dataframe does not create `id_num` column (`View(pwt10.0` does not show any variable called `id_num`). I revised my question a bit, could you let me know if I miss anything from your suggestion?

Comment: You need to assign the output back to the dataframe. See updated answer. Also `distinct(isocode)` keeps only unique rows, you may remove it if you want to keep the duplicates.